# MVC AuthorizeAttribute Class and exsiting table

Tags: model-view-controller, authorize-attribute

I have an exsiting MVC project(I'm new to MVC), and now I need to add a Login section.
I already have a table with users and passwords, that I need to use them.

How can I combine the two, by using AuthorizeAttribute Class?
I already using the DB (with a connectionString) and everything works perfectly, I just can't realize how to "tell" the AccountController to work with a specific table in my DB.

Any help will be appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.
On Global.asax:

WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ConnectionString", "tableName", "Id", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);